# Why do people use double NOT before evaluating an expression?

Tags: javascript, evaluation

`enter code here`I have often seen this --

`if(!!somevalue)`

I don't know why do people use `!!` and instead they could just write this --

`if(somevalue)`

because as far as I know

```
somevalue === !!somevalue
```

I do not have any issue but I am just curious as in what is the reason behind it?

Comment: they want a boolean as a result, so they make the expression a boolean. don't look for reason behind what a lot of people do in JS. i've even seen if(Boolean(val)===true)! at least they used a strong equality compare right? old-fashioned coders often don't understand the way JS coerces types, and they are used to spelling it out. maybe to them it's more readable.

Comment: In an `if` statement seems rather useless.